# Should I patch my intranet SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, security, administration, patching

SharePoint patching is a hassle and takes a lot of time to test and deploy,

My SharePoint is an intranet site (within my organization's premises).

Some fellow IT admins advised me to patch only major SPs, what is the common practice?

**EDIT:**
One of my major concerns is security patches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's "Official" stance is exactly that - only apply the most recent service pack to the farm.  You are only supposed to apply the Cumulative Updates if there are fixes that you need in that update.

In practice however, it is often useful to apply the most recent CU to a farm every 6-8 months as there are hundreds of small fixes in each CU and chances are pretty good that your user base is hitting their heads against some of them.  They might not be reporting it, but they probably are getting frustrated by it.

Comment: Does this recommendation apply for security patches too? Can you please also provide a link with that recommendation? Thanks.

Comment: Security Patches?  Do you mean Windows OS Patches?

Comment: No, I mean SharePoint security patches

Comment: SharePoint does not have anything called "Security Patches" so I'm not clear on what you are asking about

Comment: Example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms11-074

Comment: SharePoint patches are available in 3 forms: a Service Pack, Cumulative Update and Hotfix.  The general rules are: always apply the latest Service Pack (after testing) and then apply the CU that includes fixes for issues you are currently experiencing.  Hotfixes are only available by request from Microsoft and should only be applied if you are being affected by the issue defined.  For Intranet Sites, it is almost never required to apply a hotfix and rarely requires Cumulative Updates.  I've also seen some companies only apply the Service Packs as needed as well.

Comment: Go to any CU (great list at [Todd Klindts blog](http://www.toddklindt.com/sp2010builds)) either directly there or if you click a link to any of the Hotfixes like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2281364) you'll find a text like "...However, this hotfix is intended to correct only the problem that is described in this article. Apply this hotfix only to systems that are experiencing the problem described in this article. ... Therefore, if you are not severely affected by this problem, we recommend that you wait for the next software update that contains this hotfix."

Comment: My best practice is this:
Service Packs, apply by default
Cumulative updates, justify the need, make sure the pack is mature enough (for example they PULLED the April 2012 CU for SharePoint 2010 as problematic) then apply.  I generally do not apply CU's unless there's a valid need.
Hotfixes, similar criteria but the farm better have a critical problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a server security product that includes virtual patching (aka vulnerability shielding). Some of the AV products have this as an option.

Comment: Do you know any specific products that do that?